# Is it possible to create an in-memory SQLite database from an existing chunk of memory?

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption

From the documentation it looks like this is not possible, but I want to be sure. Here's my use case:

I want an encrypted database. It should only be decrypted while it is in memory (while the program is running). The only way I can see to do this would be to decrypt a file from disk before handing it off to SQLite. But I cannot find any way to give SQLite a pointer and say, "Here, this is a database." Nor can I find a way to serialize an in-memory database and then encrypt it before writing to disk. I assume the [sqlite3_backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) would need an unencrypted database file?

I'm running on Android, so I'd like to use the built-in SQLite and I don't think it will be possible to install [SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE)](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html). (Running on Android also means I don't have full access to the C++ API, but we can ignore that for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can replace the functions sqlite uses to interact with the filesystem from the application using the [sqlite_vfs_register](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/vfs_find.html) method, it should be possible. I don't have experience with the encryption extension, but there is a chance that it uses this interface too, so it might be even possible to use it.

Comment: Whew, yikes, that [sqlite3_vfs struct](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/vfs.html) seems like a pretty hefty interface to implement. Will I be able to extend their existing implementation at all? I'm a novice when it comes to C. :-(

Comment: Yes, you should be able to extend existing implementation. Use the `sqlite_vfs_find` to get hands on the default one. Than you can use the same function pointers for methods you don't need to change (all but xOpen and maybe xDelete--the magic happens in the `sqlite3_io_methods` you set in the `sqlite3_file`) and you can call the pointers from the default interface in the rest. However, first have a look whether SEE uses that API (I don't have the source for it, so I can't), because it probably does and if it does, it should just work.